# C++11 setting lambda in public function

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

how to properly address this?

```
 class House{
 public:
  void startAction();
  void init(){
      startAction = [] () {}; 
  }  
 };
```

I have tried this, but it is said "Expression is not assignable"

I want to define the function of startAction, but inside the init method.

I do this because there's couple of variable in init method that i want to capture to pass to startAction.

Comment: use std::function for startAction

Comment: why not capture the values in `House`? The values seemed to be owned by it, from your description

Comment: thanks, I really don't want to capture it in House, as i want to destroy it as init end.

Comment: Is there a rationale behind that two-step construction?

Comment: @GulperEeL It doesn't really matter whether you store those values as members in the object or in the function's closure. The only difference is whether they're accessible from other member function sor not.

Comment: I still find it remarkable that folks adopt this two-step construction. Where I'm from we tend to initialize members in (mostly before the body of) a ctor. Has that gotten of fashion somehow? :)

Comment: How is it two-step construction? I should call it InitAction if i want  to make two-step construction. The logic is the object would be built but the action will be started if another object call it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
class House {
  public:
    std::function<void ()> startAction;
    void init() {
        startAction = []() {};
    }  
};

int main() {
    House house;
    house.init();
    house.startAction();
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can't assign a value to a member function.

You could have a member variable that the member function calls, something like this:

```
class House{
 public:
  void startAction() { m_action(); }
  void init(){
      m_action = [] () {}; 
  }
 private:
  std::function<void()> m_action;  
};
```

But it's simpler to store the things you want to capture as members of `House`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also instead of using `std::function<void ()>` use C style pointer to function. Look at the following code.

```
#include <iostream>

typedef void (*my_func)();

class House
{
public:
    my_func  m_ffunc;

    void init()
    {
        m_ffunc = [](){ std::cout << "Hello from m_ffunc" << std::endl;};
    }
};

int main()
{
    House myHouse;

    myHouse.init();
    myHouse.m_ffunc();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "there's couple of variable in init method that i want to capture". C-style pointers to function cannot capture variables. This doesn't answer the question.